# how to show dynamic data in bootstrap modal within loop

Tags: php, html, css, modal-dialog

So, I want to show detail data from row that I clicked. I clicked from looping data showing in table. here is the code.

```
$fetchall = "SELECT * FROM data";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $fetchall);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$id2 = $row['id'];
$no_1 = $row['number'];
$status_1 = $row['status'];
<td style="font-size: 10pt; width:7px;background-color:#4C724A; opacity:0.7; color:white">
<a style="background-color:#5a85dd; color:white; padding:10px; border-radius:10px; margin-top:20px; " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#popUpIA<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"></a></td>}<?php}?>
```

and this is my modal code.

```
<div class="modal fade"  id="popUpIA<?php echo $id2 ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="popUpIATitle" aria-hidden="true">
                      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg"  style="background-color: #4C724A; width:50%" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                          <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="popUpIATitle"></h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-body">
                          <!-- <table style="width:100%"> -->
```

the problem is, modal can only popup when i clicked the last record and only can get the last id

Comment: Looks like you are not even creating the modal _inside_ the loop.

Comment: @CBroe I've tried modal inside the loop but the modal show in the bottom page instead of being popup. I read another source, it suggest to write modal outside the loop

Comment: _"it suggest to write modal outside the loop"_ - then how would you expect to get an individual modal for each record? Then you would need to use JavaScript on the client side, to _read_ the data from the triggering element, and dynamically populate your modal with that, at the moment it gets shown.

Comment: Just in case you want to take the dynamic route, Bootstrap has an example on [varying modal content](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/modal/#varying-modal-content) including JS to fill the modal

Comment: @CBroe thank you for the enlightenment. So I should add javascript. Ok I'll try. Thanks again